# type A requires that type B be a class type swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

the following code gives me a compile error

> 'WeakReference' requires that 'ServiceDelegate' be a class type

```
protocol ServiceDelegate: AnyObject {
    func doIt()
}

class SomeClass() {
    // compile error occurs in this line
    private var observers = [WeakReference<ServiceDelegate>]()
}
```

WeakReference code:

```
final class WeakReference<T: AnyObject> {

    private(set) weak var value: T?

    init(value: T?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error? Delegate should be declared correctly as per this [site](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/class-only-protocols-in-swift-4/).

What I have tried so far:

- Changing the delegate protocol conformance from `AnyObject` to
  `class` does not solve the problem.
- Try the above code in a clean playground.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't have a `WeakReference<ServiceDelegate>`.  `ServiceDelegate` itself is not an `AnyObject`, it just requires that anything that conforms to it be an `AnyObject`.

You would need to make `SomeClass` generic and use the generic type as the type for the `WeakReference`:

```
class SomeClass<T: ServiceDelegate> {
    private var observers = [WeakReference<T>]()
}
```

If the generic on `SomeClass` is too constricting and you want to be able to have instances of multiple unrelated classes as observers then I would do it by abandoning the generic parameter on `WeakReference`:

```
final class WeakServiceDelegate {
    private(set) weak var value: ServiceDelegate?

    init(value: ServiceDelegate?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    private var observers = [WeakServiceDelegate]()
}
```

Alternatively you could make `WeakReference` conditionally conform to `ServiceDelegate`:

```
extension WeakReference: ServiceDelegate where T: ServiceDelegate {
    func doIt() {
        value?.doIt()
    }
}
```

And then use an array of `ServiceDelegate` in `SomeClass`:

```
class SomeClass {
    private var observers = [ServiceDelegate]()

    func addObserver<T: ServiceDelegate>(_ observer: T) {
        observers.append(WeakReference(value: observer))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As you see, `ServiceDelegate` is a protocol, not a class type.
Even if all types which can conform to `ServiceDelegate` are class types, `ServiceDelegate` itself is not a class type. It is the fact of the pure Swift protocols currently.

Try `@obc`, Objective-C protocols are a bit different:

```
@objc protocol ServiceDelegate {
    func doIt()
}
```

You may want to exclude Objective-C something and to make some pure Swift classes conform to `ServiceDelegate`, but I cannot find other ways around.

Comment: This is bizarre. Even marking the protocol as NSObjectProtocol doesn't help, but marking it with @objc resolves... Great thing, anyway!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `WeakReference<ServiceDelegate>` is wrong at line

`private var observers = [WeakReference<ServiceDelegate>]()`

You have to use a concrete class instead of protocol inside `<>`

You have two possible solutions:

1. Create a concrete class and use it:

> ```
> class ServiceClass: ServiceDelegate {
> //...
> }
> private var observers = [WeakReference<ServiceClass>]()
> ```

2. Or use a protocol. I mean this:

   ```
    final class WeakReference<T: AnyObject> {

        private(set) weak var value: T?

        init(value: T?) {
            self.value = value
        }
    }

    protocol SomeContainer: AnyObject { }
    extension WeakReference: SomeContainer { }
   ```

and use this way:

```
 private var observers = [SomeContainer]()
```

**Note**

Using this way:

```
class SomeClass<T: ServiceDelegate> {
    private var observers = [WeakReference<T>]()
}
```

You just move the problem to another part of the code.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem and ended up keeping generic `WeakReference`, but removing type constraint:

```
struct WeakReference<T> {
    private weak var storage: AnyObject?
    var value: T? {
        get { return storage.map { $0 as! T } }
        set {
            storage = newValue.map { $0 as AnyObject }
        }
    }

    init(value: T?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

This works for classes, Objective-C protocols and Swift protocols:

```
protocol P: class {}
@objc protocol Q {}

class Z: P, Q {}

var z = Z()
var rz = WeakReference<Z>(value: z)
var rp = WeakReference<P>(value: z)
var rq = WeakReference<Q>(value: z)
assert(rz.value === z)
assert(rp.value === z)
assert(rq.value === z)
z = Z()
assert(rz.value === nil)
assert(rp.value === nil)
assert(rq.value === nil)
```

Unfortunately it compiles for other things too:

```
protocol R {}
struct S: R {}
var rr = WeakReference<R>(value: S())
print("rr =", rr.value as Any) // nil
var rs = WeakReference<S>(value: S())
print("rs =", rs.value as Any) // nil
```

In Swift anything can be casted to `AnyObject`, but for value types that means boxing - new instance is allocated and immediately lost, so it always produces nil.

This can be used to implement an assertion that casting to `AnyObject` preserves identity:

```
struct WeakReference<T> {
    private weak var storage: AnyObject?
    var value: T? {
        get { return storage.map { $0 as! T } }
        set {
            storage = newValue.map {
                let asObject = $0 as AnyObject
                assert(asObject === $0 as AnyObject)
                return asObject
            }
        }
    }

    init(value: T?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Alternative approach would be to use https://github.com/wickwirew/Runtime to validate kind of `T.self`.

Answer (score 3):

create plain protocol

```
public protocol AnyWeakValue {
    var anyValue: Any? { get }
}
```

inherit associatedtype protocol from **AnyWeakValue**

```
public protocol WeakValue: AnyWeakValue {
    associatedtype ValueType
    var value: ValueType? { get }
}

extension WeakValue {
    public var anyValue: Any? { return value }
}
```

create class Weak inherit **WeakValue**

```
open class Weak<Value: AnyObject>: WeakValue {
    public init(value: Value?) { self.value = value }
    open private(set) weak var value: Value?
}
```

using example

```
private var _delegates: [AnyWeakValue] = []
public var delegates: [SomeProtocol] {
    return _delegates.compactMap({$0.anyValue as? SomeProtocol})
}

public func register<Delegate>(_ delegate: Delegate) where Delegate: SomeProtocol {
    let weak: Weak<Delegate> = Weak.init(value: delegate)
    _delegates.append(weak)
}
```