# 'Box' requires that 'CanFly' be a class type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift5, associated-types

### Background

Let's consider the following working code

```
protocol CanFly { }

protocol Container {
    associatedtype ContentType
    var value: ContentType? { get }
}

class Box<V>: Container {
    var value: V?
}

let box = Box<CanFly>()
box.value // <- has type `CanFly?`
```

> Here `Box` accepts a protocol as generic type, beautiful isn't it?

### Things get harder

Now I want to do a "small" change, I make the `value` property in Box `weak`

```
class Box<V>: Container {
    weak var value: V?
}
```

And of course I get this error

```
class Box<V>: Container {
    weak var value: V? // 'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'V'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound
}
```

I try to fix it constraining `V` to be an `AnyObject`

```
class Box<V:AnyObject>: Container {
    weak var value: V?
}
```

And I get this error

```
let box = Box<CanFly>() // 'Box' requires that 'CanFly' be a class type
```

### The problem

The problem here is that since I defined `V:AnyObject` I can no longer use the protocol `CanFly` as generic type of `Box`.

### The question

I want

1. to be able to use a protocol as generic type of Box
2. **AND** the `Box#value` property to be `weak`

How can I do that?

### Final considerations

I am looking for something like this

```
class Box<V:ProtocolForClassOnly>: Container {
    weak var value: V?
}
```

> P.S. The closest question on StackOverflow I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486965/type-a-requires-that-type-b-be-a-class-type-swift-4) but unfortunately hasn't helped me.

Comment: I'm confused about your P.S. That question seems identical to your question, and the answer appears correct. Do you believe that answer is not correct? Or are you just hoping that answer isn't correct? (It is correct; you can't do what you're trying to do exactly the way you're trying to do it.)

Comment: If you're looking for more solutions than the ones there, then I would look hard at using closures (that may have a `weak` capture) rather than trying to create multiple levels of protocols like this. If you can discuss your underlying problem that this solves, I suspect we can build a closure-based solution and avoid delegate-style patterns.

Answer (score -1):

So constrain your CanFly protocol to type AnyObject:

```
protocol CanFly: AnyObject { }

protocol Container {
    associatedtype ContentType
    var value: ContentType? { get }
}

class Box<V>: Container {
    var value: V?
}
```

Then your code works:

```
func foo() {
    let box = Box<CanFly>()
    print(type(of:box.value))
}
```

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for your answer. However I need the `value` property to be `weak`.

Comment: "I need the value property to be weak." That's not a thing. value properties don't have weak/strong memory semantics at all.

Comment: That's right, indeed I want the `value` property in `Box` to be populated with an `object`. I don't want a value type property.